# LUA nil value error after touch event

Tags: for-loop, lua, drag-and-drop, coronasdk, lua-table

So this question is related to the question I posted yesterday [LINK!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615777/lua-for-loop-does-not-iterate-properly). I'm currently working on an elevator game and i'm trying to move a passenger based on the y value of the elevator(lift).

```
function moveLift(event)
    for i=1,PASSENGER_AMOUNT do
        for j=1,4 do
            if passengers[i].travelling == true then
                if event.phase == "began" then
                    markY = event.target.y
                    passengers[i].y = event.target.y
                elseif event.phase == "moved" then
                    local y = (event.y - event.yStart) + markY
                    event.target.y = y
                    passengers[i].y = event.target.y
                elseif event.phase == "ended" then

                    if (hasCollided( event.target, hotSpots[j] )) then

                        if (event.target.destination == hotSpots[j].floor) then
                            if event.target.occupied == true then

                                display.remove(floorText)
                                floorText = nil

                                gameAreaGroup.remove(passengers[i])
                                passengers[i] = nil

                                succesfullPassengers = succesfullPassengers + 1

                                if succesfullPassengers == PASSENGER_AMOUNT then
                                    gameIsOver = true
                                    createDialogue("Congratulations! You have completed the level!")
                                    for i=1,LIFT_AMOUNT,1 do
                                        lifts[i]:removeEventListener( "touch", moveLift )
                                    end
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When a passenger enters the elevator, i set a boolean called travelling to true so I know the passenger can be moved.But when I move the elevator to the correct floor (random value between 1-4) i receive an error (attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)) on line 96, which is:

```
if passengers[i].travelling == true then
```

So my guess is that the passenger isnt removed propperly, right?

Comment: That error means that there is no data at index `i` for whatever value of `i` that is. Which either means `PASSENGER_AMOUNT` is larger than the length of the table or some other passenger index is `nil` in the middle. Where does `PASSENGER_AMOUNT` come from? Why are you not using `#passengers` or something similar?

Comment: PASSENGER_AMOUNT is the total amount of passengers created in the game (which is 2). I use this variable in the function that creates the passengers.

Comment: Which value is that line complaining about? `1` or `2`? Does that index in the `passengers` table have a value?

Comment: attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)  is the only thing i get and it does have a value, i create passengers using:

passengers[i] = display.newImageRect(passengerImages[i],15,35)

Comment: passengerImages[] is a table which holds 2 images

Comment: So, currently i have changed:
gameAreaGroup.remove(passengers[i]) passengers[i] = nil to passengers[i]:removeSelf() --passengers[i] = nil
which seems to work for the first passenger but when the second passenger is deleted it says:
attempt to call method 'removeSelf' (a nil value) stack traceback

Comment: Does `gameAreaGroup.remove` or `removeSelf` modify the passengers table? Does it use `table.remove` or move the entries down to close holes or anything?